# openFrameworks: How to allow two event keys to occur simultaneously

Tags: c++, openframeworks

Problem: I want to make my ship sprite move around the screen with the basic WASD keys. I've accomplished this, but the problem is that when I hit two keys (e.g. W and D), the ship doesn't move in a diagonal fashion as I expect it to. Instead, it moves according to which key was hit most recently.

Holding one key will make it move as long as I hold it. What is the set up for 2 (and multiple)?

My code (blueship is a class with the self-explanatory methods shown):

```
void testApp::keyPressed(int key)
{
    if (key == 'w')
    {
        blueship.move_up();
    }
    if (key == 's')
    {
        blueship.move_down();
    }
    if (key == 'a')
    {
        blueship.move_left();
    }
    if (key == 'd')
    {
        blueship.move_right();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

keyReleased event?

```
key W is pressed -> move up
key W is release -> stop moving
key A is pressed -> move left
key S is pressed -> move left + move down (key A is not released,yet)
```